# Django creating table with hyperlink in cells

Tags: django, html-table, django-views

I want to display table with basic informations about products, and add hyperlink to cells in column "Product name" after clicking which you will be redirected to more detailed description of product with possibility to edtiing, deleting it etc.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-dark">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Product name</th>
                            <th scope="col">Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for element in object %}             
            <tr>
                <td><div class="btn active"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div></td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{% url 'prod_desc' pk:element.pk %}">
                        {{element.name|lower|capfirst}}
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{element.price}}
                </td>
            </tr>               
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I connect hiperlink with product name in table?
In case is there any walk-around solution ?
Is there any restriction about inserting hyperlink in html in general or it's a "Django thing" ?

Comment: Your for loop dont have `{% endfor %}` tag. and also `</tr>` is missing

Comment: What error are you facing ?

Comment: There is no literally an error, just hiperlink is not getting connected into <td> element

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in passing primary key of element I used ":" like in dictionary key:value instead of "="

```
                    <a href="{% url 'prod_desc' pk=element.pk %}">
                        {{element.name|lower|capfirst}}
                    </a>
```